# PGF: 2 x axes without a second plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I would like to add a second x axis to my single plot. The first x axis goes from 0 to 2, the second one goes from 0 to 0.28. 0.28 on the second axis should be on the same x coordinate as 2 on the first one.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.3,transform shape]
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Spulenstrom [A]},
        ylabel={Spitze der Volumenverteilung [nm]},
        xmin=0,
        ymin=0,
        scale only axis,
        ]
        \addplot+[black, mark options ={fill = black}, mark=*, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0.25, 53.92) +- (21.76, 21.79)
        (0.5, 33.9) +- (13.81,13.81)
        (0.75, 29.54) +- (11.72, 11.72)
        (1, 27.35) +- (12.42, 12.42)
        (1.25, 30.38) +- (12.66, 12.66)
        (1.5, 24.97) +- (15.08, 15.08)
        (1.75, 34.46) +- (16.92, 16.92)
        (2, 30.2) +- (13.34, 13.34)
        };
        \end{axis}
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {magnetische Flussdichte [T]},
        xmin = 0, xmax = 0.28, axis x line*=top, axis y line = none, scale only axis,
        ]
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is my current code which isn't working. I tried several examples for second y and x axes but all of them assume a second plot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/riLIB.png This is the picture I currently get with this code

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it, but it seems like a really crufty hack.
I just plotted the same data again but made it transparent.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel={Spulenstrom [A]},
        ylabel={Spitze der Volumenverteilung [nm]},
        xmin=0, 
        ymin=0,
        scale only axis,
        ]
        \addplot+[black, mark options ={fill = black}, mark=*, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit,] coordinates {
        (0.25, 53.92) +- (21.76, 21.79)
        (0.5, 33.9) +- (13.81,13.81)
        (0.75, 29.54) +- (11.72, 11.72)
        (1, 27.35) +- (12.42, 12.42)
        (1.25, 30.38) +- (12.66, 12.66)
        (1.5, 24.97) +- (15.08, 15.08)
        (1.75, 34.46) +- (16.92, 16.92)
        (2, 30.2) +- (13.34, 13.34)
        };
        \end{axis}
        
        \begin{axis}[
        xlabel = {Magnetische Flussdichte [T]}, xmin = 0, ymin = 0, tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
        axis x line*=top, axis y line = none, scale only axis, xtick = {0, 0.07, 0.14, 0.21, 0.28}
        ]
        \addplot+[black, draw opacity = 0, fill opacity = 0, mark options ={fill = black}, mark=*, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit, ] coordinates {
        (0.035, 53.92) +- (21.76, 21.79)
        (0.07, 33.9) +- (13.81,13.81)
        (0.105, 29.54) +- (11.72, 11.72)
        (0.14, 27.35) +- (12.42, 12.42)
        (0.175, 30.38) +- (12.66, 12.66)
        (0.21, 24.97) +- (15.08, 15.08)
        (0.245, 34.46) +- (16.92, 16.92)
        (0.28, 30.2) +- (13.34, 13.34)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Maybe just this `\addplot[draw opacity = 0, fill opacity = 0] coordinates {(0.0) (0.28, 0)};`. I would think it better to have the data only one place.